# Obtener y convertir a valor numérico, etiqueta seleccionada a través de selectInput() de Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Necesito hacer una aplicación shiny que obtenga el valor de una fórmula donde el usuario ingrese los valores de las variables a través numericInput y selectInput. Con el primero el reemplazo es directo pero no logro encontrar cómo obtener la opción seleccionada en selectInput, convertirla para poder incluir su valor a la fórmula. La relación de los opciones de selectInput de Situacion Laboral del padre es por ejemplo "Trabaja"=1; "No trabaja"=2. El código que realicé es:

```
library(shiny)
ui<-navbarPage("REGRESION LOGISTICA",
           tabPanel("RESULTADO",
                    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                                                h5(helpText("Seleccione valores de las siguientes variables")),
                                               tags$hr(), 
                                              # radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', 
                                                #             choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ','),
                                               selectInput("var", 
                                                           label = "Seleccione Nivel de Estudio de la madre",
                                                           choices = c("Primaria Incompleta", 
                                                                       "Primaria Completa",
                                                                       "Secundario Incompleto", 
                                                                       "Secundario Completo",
                                                                       "Estudio Superior/Universitario Incompleto", 
                                                                       "Estudio Superior/ Universitario Completo"),
                                                           selected = "Secundario Completo"),
                                              selectInput("var2", 
                                                          label = "Seleccione Situacion laboral del padre",
                                                          choices = c("Trabaja", "No trabaja"),
                                                            selected = "Trabaja")),

                    mainPanel(#uiOutput("tb1")
                      numericInput("num_W", "Materias Regulares:", 0,min = 0, max = 15),
                      numericInput("num_l", "Edad:", 15,min = 15, max = 56),
                      h5(textOutput("Prueba")))
                    ) ))

server<-function(input,output) { 
  #output$Prueba <- renderText({ 
  # "La probabilidad de que el alumno NO continue sus estudios es:"
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    vals$W <- input$num_W
    vals$L <- input$num_l
  })
  output$Prueba <- renderText({
    paste("1.26624*Regulares+0.05381*Edad+EstMadreR+0.25075*SitLaboralPadre=", 
    1.26624*vals$W+0.05381*vals$L)
  })
  }
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Podría alguien orientarme por favor???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, tes sugiero que definas dos `data,frame` para manejar las opciones y los "coeficientes", por ejemplo:

```
opciones_laborales <- data.frame(nombre = c("Trabaja", "No trabaja"),
                                 coeficiente = c(1,2), 
                                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
opciones_estudio <- data.frame(nombre = c("Primaria Incompleta", "Primaria Completa",
                                          "Secundario Incompleto", "Secundario Completo",
                                          "Estudio Superior/Universitario Incompleto", 
                                          "Estudio Superior/ Universitario Completo"),
                      coeficiente = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Luego, aprovecha que ya tienes esto y usa estos objetos para definir los combos. Por ejemplo:

```
selectInput("var", 
            label = "Seleccione Nivel de Estudio de la madre",
            choices = opciones_estudio$nombre,
            selected = opciones_estudio$nombre[4])
```

Luego deberías "observar" los dos combos para capturar las acciones del usuario con ellos:

```
observe({
    vals$W <- input$num_W
    vals$L <- input$num_l
    vals$Var <- input$var
    vals$Var2 <- input$var2
})
```

Y por último, la construcción del texto, simplemente deberás ver según la opción seleccionada, el coeficiente que le corresponde

```
  output$Prueba <- renderText({

    o_estudio <- opciones_estudio$coeficiente[opciones_estudio$nombre == vals$Var]
    o_laboral <- opciones_laborales$coeficiente[opciones_laborales$nombre == vals$Var2]

    paste("1.26624*Regulares+0.05381*Edad+EstMadreR+0.25075*SitLaboralPadre=", 
          1.26624*vals$W+0.05381*vals$L+o_estudio+o_laboral*0.25075)
  })
```

El código final completo:

```
library(shiny)

opciones_laborales <- data.frame(nombre = c("Trabaja", "No trabaja"),
                                 coeficiente = c(1,2), 
                                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
opciones_estudio <- data.frame(nombre = c("Primaria Incompleta", "Primaria Completa",
                                          "Secundario Incompleto", "Secundario Completo",
                                          "Estudio Superior/Universitario Incompleto", 
                                          "Estudio Superior/ Universitario Completo"),
                      coeficiente = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


ui<-navbarPage("REGRESION LOGISTICA",
               tabPanel("RESULTADO",
                        sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                          h5(helpText("Seleccione valores de las siguientes variables")),
                          tags$hr(), 
                          # radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', 
                          #             choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ','),
                          selectInput("var", 
                                      label = "Seleccione Nivel de Estudio de la madre",
                                      choices = opciones_estudio$nombre,
                                      selected = opciones_estudio$nombre[4]),
                          selectInput("var2", 
                                      label = "Seleccione Situacion laboral del padre",
                                      choices = opciones_laborales$nombre,
                                      selected = opciones_laborales$nombre[1])),

                          mainPanel(#uiOutput("tb1")
                            numericInput("num_W", "Materias Regulares:", 0,min = 0, max = 15),
                            numericInput("num_l", "Edad:", 15,min = 15, max = 56),
                            h5(textOutput("Prueba")))
                        ) ))

server<-function(input,output) { 
  #output$Prueba <- renderText({ 
  # "La probabilidad de que el alumno NO continue sus estudios es:"
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    vals$W <- input$num_W
    vals$L <- input$num_l
    vals$Var <- input$var
    vals$Var2 <- input$var2
  })
  output$Prueba <- renderText({

    o_estudio <- opciones_estudio$coeficiente[opciones_estudio$nombre == vals$Var]
    o_laboral <- opciones_laborales$coeficiente[opciones_laborales$nombre == vals$Var2]

    paste("1.26624*Regulares+0.05381*Edad+EstMadreR+0.25075*SitLaboralPadre=", 
          1.26624*vals$W+0.05381*vals$L+o_estudio+o_laboral*0.25075)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Muuuchas gracias Patricio!, funciona correctamente. Slds